# Beamer theme Metropolis conflicts with option in epstopdf.cfg

Tags: epstopdf, beamer-metropolis

The following MWE fails in texlive 2021 (pdflatex):

```
\documentclass[handout,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\title{Testing}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Hello}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is

```
/Users/themis/Library/texmf/tex/latex/config/epstopdf.cfg:1: Undefined control 
sequence.
\ETE@prepend ->\PrependGraphicsExtensions 
                                          {.eps}
l.1 ...{update,prepend,prefersuffix=false,suffix=}
```

and is caused by epstopdf.cfg in my local tree, which contains the command

```
\epstopdfsetup{update,prepend,prefersuffix=false,suffix=}
```

The error occurs only when I use `\usetheme{metropolis}`. If I comment out the metropolis theme the code runs fine. I did not have this problem in my previous installation, which was an older texlive, though I can't remember which.

If I remove `prepend` from the options in `\epstopdfsetup`  metropolis runs OK, but then I don't get an updated PDF when I update the EPS graphic.

If I remove file `epstopdf.cfg` altogether, Metropolis runs but I get `eps-converted-to` attached to the names of the PDF graphics. This is something I am trying to avoid.

My question is: how do I get Metropolis to convert EPS files without the `eps-converted-to`?

Comment: _This is something I am trying to avoid_ why exactly? Do you want to re-use the converted pdf somewhere? Or do you consider the generated filenames unnecessary?

Comment: @Marijn Not sure how your question helps. My question is this: does the user have the ability to override the name of the converted file? This should have a yes or no answer.

Comment: you are missing the grfext package, with `\usepackage{grfext}` it no longer errors, but I'm not sure why it fails only with pgf.

Comment: @Themis I asked the question because many times (although not always) it can help to know more about the use case of a question, to give a more suitable answer, to suggest alternatives, or in some cases to challenge the premise. In this case the comment from Ulrike suggests a simple solution, but if a simple solution is not available then somebody could for example write a separate macro to add the suffix for re-using the converted file if it was clear from the question that that was the reason for not wanting to change the filenames.

Comment: imho there is small bug in epstopdf-base which leads to the error. But beside this: if you want to use extended options of epstopdf you should load the required packages (here e.g. grfext, or epstopdf). The automatically loaded epstopdf-base will not do it on its own.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, `\usepackage{grfext}` fixes the issue. If you post as a reply I will mark it accepted.

Comment: @Marijn Understood – thanks.